# How to disable other opitons when one option is selected of “radio buttons”?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to disable other options immediately once an option is selected but using java-script I could not do this. Please help me. I have tried so far

```
 <?php 
    $answer = $exm->getAnswer($number);

    if ($answer) {
        while ($result = $answer->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 <input id="question_radio" type="radio" name="ans" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"/><?php echo $result['ans']; ?>



<script id="question_radio" type="text/javascript">$(":radio").click(function(){
   var radioName = $(this).attr("ans"); //Get radio name
  $(":radio[name='"+radioName+"']:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true); //Disable all unchecked radios with the same name
});             

            </script>


                </td>
            </tr>
<?php } } ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next Question"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />

                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: you mean when one radio button is selected then you need to disable other radio button ? but why ? because we can only select one radio buton at a time with same name and only the selected radio button will get submitted ..

Comment: but why ? @ Swati --> Because I am trying to develop a small project using what my students can have some "Online multiple choice" exams. The point in real life once an option is selected on paper, once can not touch the other, I want them to be very attentive so that they can have same feeling and do not touch the wrong one, even by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `name` attribute of the radio which is `clicked` and depending on this we will loop through all the radio button with that name and `disable` radio button which are not checked.

Here is demo code :

```js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
  //getting name attribute if radio which is clicked
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  console.log(name)
  //loop only through those radio where name is same
  $('input[name="' + name + '"]').each(function() {
    //if not selected
    if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
      // add disable
      $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="question_radio" type="radio" name="ans" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" /> A
<input id="question_radio" type="radio" name="ans" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" />B
<input id="question_radio" type="radio" name="ans" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" />C
<br>
<input id="question_radio" type="radio" name="ans1" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" />A
<input id="question_radio" type="radio" name="ans1" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" /> B

<input id="question_radio" type="radio" name="ans1" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" />C
```

Comment: thank you. It will help not only me but also my students.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation in pure Javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]").forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //getting name attribute if radio which is clicked
    var name = el.getAttribute('name');
    //loop only through those radio where name is same.
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + name + '"]').forEach(function (el) {
      if (el.matches(":not(:checked)")) {
        el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    });
  });
});
```